# Effect on kinetic energy of a body with change in temperature

Tags: energy, temperature

Why doesn’t the energy of a body doubles when temperature in degrees Celsius is doubled?
I know that it doubles in case of kelvin scale.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Finally, we have an important policy: your questions (especially [homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/189)), should show your own work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

You might find it interesting to read up on the differences between the different temperature scales. The kelvin scale effectively measures the vibration (average kinetic energy of molecules) so it makes sense that a doubling in the kelvin means a doubling in kinetic energy. On the other hand the Celsius scale is defined by the melting and boiling points of water (quite arbitrary).